# Выделение запятыми слова "пожалуйста"

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова

"Закрывайте пожалуйста дверь!". Нужны ли запятые вокруг слова *пожалуйста*? Если нет, то почему? Я бы поставила, решив, что это вводное слово.

Answer (score 15):

Правильно: Закрывайте, пожалуйста, дверь (вводное слово).

У Розенталя http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/47.htm

1. Передайте, пожалуйста, эту рукопись редактору (пожалуйста – вводное слово в значении «прошу вас»).
2. Скажи пожалуйста, какой храбрец! (цельное сочетание скажи пожалуйста при выражении удивления, возмущения, негодования).
3. Вечером пожалуйста, а днем прийти не могу (пожалуйста – частица для выражения согласия, в значении «да»).

Answer (score 6):

Это и есть вводное слово, поэтому запятые нужны

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **Закрывайте, пожалуйста, дверь.**
Почему? Предлагаю не думать на секунду о тонкостях терминологии или правил.

1. Если убрать слово *пожалуйста*, то смысл не изменится - Закрывайте дверь. Значит, это слово надо выделить запятыми чтобы не запутать читающего.
   Если смысл изменится, то ясно что нельзя ставить запятые. Например, "Оставьте ваши пожалуйста. Надоело. Это не делает вас вежливым."
2. Запятые являются вспомогательными элементами с помощью которых мы помогаем читателю понять смысл того что хотим сказать. Ведь запятая заставляет остановиться выделяя элемент в запятых. Например, если не поставить запятых, то читатель "споткнется" - "Закройте пожалуйста... ." Как можно закрыть *пожалуйста*? Или запутаем читателя - "Скажи пожалуйста, какой умный." или "Скажи, пожалуйста, какой умный." Ясно что первый вариант логичен, а второй нет. Если выбрать второй, то читатель будет сомневаться в смысле сказанного: может речь идет о *который* умный, а не *какой*, но тогда потребуется *?*.

Comment: _Запятые являются вспомогательными элементами с помощью которых мы помогаем читателю понять смысл того что хотим сказать._ Отчасти согласна. Но тогда уж и Вы расставьте необходимые знаки препинания.

Comment: 1. Предлагаете что-то объяснить без правил? Это пожалуйста, с большим удовольствием! (Кстати, запятую здесь не ставим).  
2. Мы не роботы, нас не запутаешь!  Смысл сказанного определяем по ситуации. Например: У меня нет наушников. Оставьте ваши,  пожалуйста.  А вот в предложении «Оставьте ваши «пожалуйста» желательно поставить кавычки – для ясности и быстрого понимания, так как фраза нестандартная.
2. Для чего мы обособляем «пожалуйста»? Думаю, чтобы оно «не  путалось под глазами» и не мешало прочтению основного текста.  Это такой маркер вежливости.

Comment: 3. Скажите пожалуйста, какой умный!  Нет-нет, это я не про вас, мне нравится, когда люди думают, я даже за вас проголосую (будете у нас на первом месте –  за неделю и месяц). А как объяснить эту фразу? Она выражает иронию, на каково ее происхождение?
4. И еще вопрос. На письме «пожалуйста» выделяется запятыми, а как же быть в устной речи?  Здесь возможен стандартный ответ: на письме выделяем запятыми, а в речи паузами.  Но паузу иногда не получается поставить, например: Закрой, пожалуйста, двЕрь и не мешай рабОтать. Как нам здесь «не закрыть пожалуйста»?

Comment: Может и желательно взять слово пожалуйста в кавычки, но тут есть одно но. Кавычки одного слова могут указывать на подтекст или на другое значение. Например, “Забота” правительства лишает нас средств на пропитание. 
Фраза “не мешалась под глазами” - это настоящая находка, и с ней я полностью согласен.А насчет пауз в разговорной речи, то вряд ли они всегда присутствуют.. “Проходите пожалуйста.” или “Проходите, пожАлуйста!” В первом варианте в разговоре нет паузы. Это приводит нас к следующему важному замечанию, а именно: всегда ли правило верно или, скорее всего, нужно?

Comment: Это наверно анафема, но мне кажется что нет (запятая перед что опущена). У нас в языке много правил без которых можно обойтись. Я не против правил, но каждое правило должно быть объяснимо. Например, в предложение “Думаю что это так.” правило требует запятую. А зачем? Как еще можно понять или не понять это предложение без запятой? 
Конечно, кто я такой чтобы руку на правила поднимать? Но если оглянуться вокруг то увидим что количество правил не предопределяет грамотность (предложение без запятых, но плавность и смысл не нарушены, на мой взгляд).

Comment: Я не против всех правил, только тех что мешают/не помогают. Правила должны помогать ясности изложения, а не ради самих правил. Поэтому-то в том ответе я и предложил думать о смысле, а не о правилах. 
Да, я за баллами не гонюсь и не за этим я здесь. Мне надо расширить и углубить моё понимание и знание языка, чего нельзя сделать просто читая Розенталя.