# Почему "пожалуйста" выделяется запятыми?

Tags: синтаксис, запятые

Пожалуйста - частица и вводное слово. Почему оно выделяется запятыми, даже когда оно просто частица (не вводное слово)?

См. [значения 3 и 6](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5).

В русском вроде не принято выделять частицы запятыми (вроде частицы "вроде").

Ну и если уж на то пошло, почему вообще значение 4 возведено в ранг вводного слова? Чем (синтаксически) оно отличается от употребления в значениях 5 или 6, например? Частица она и есть частица.

Если уж совсем по-рабочекрестьянски: скажите-**пжалста**, зачем эту частицу выделять запятыми? Чем она лучше скажите-**ка**, вы мне скажете **ведь**?

P.S. Вопрос продиктован ленью. Ищу поводы сэкономить на запятых.

P.P.S. Только вот не надо ответов в стиле "так сложилось". Спасибо.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выделение запятыми слова "пожалуйста"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32510/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0)

Comment: См. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/32510/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0

Comment: Вопрос этот я видел, спасибо. Мой вопрос в другом: как частица пожалуйста стала вводным словом и заслуживает ли она этого звания.

Comment: Сомневаюсь, что кто-нибудь возьмётся за анализ конвертации слов.

Answer (score 2):

Как частица - никогда, как вводное - подчиняясь общим правилам.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Вопрос № 200565](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=200565)

> Всегда ли слово "пожалуйста" выделяется запятыми? Например, "Извините
>   пожалуйста"?
>
> **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>
> Слово *пожалуйста*, как правило, обособляется или оформляется как
>   отдельное предложение. Корректно: *Извините, пожалуйста*.

[Вводные слова и конструкции на письме выделяются с двух сторон запятыми](https://5-ege.ru/vvodnye-slova/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С тем, что вводные выделяются запятыми, я не спорю. Правило есть правило. Вопрос в том, почему «пожалуйста» считается вводным словом («Постойте, пожалуйста!»), а другие частицы - нет («Постойте-ка!», «Постойте же!»)?

Comment: На вопрос "почему?" наука ответа не даёт. ТАК ПРИНЯТО,

Answer (score 2):

Частица и вводное слово — это разные грамматические понятия.

Частица — это **служебная часть речи** (вместе с предлогами и союзами). Вводные слова — это **синтаксическая функция**, но не часть речи.

**"Служба" частиц разнообразна**: в общем случае они выражают дополнительные смысловые оттенки, в том числе модальные и  эмоционально-экспрессивные (также могут служить для образования слов и словоформ). Частицы, как правило, не обособляются, но иногда обособление возможно.

**Вводными словами** могут  различные части речи. Они выражают отношение говорящего к сказанному, также служат для оформления предложения. В состав предложения не входят и **всегда обособляются.**

Пути частиц и вводных слов могут пересекаться, в частности это касается слова ***пожалуйста***.

Вводное слово ***пожалуйста*** обычно выражает вежливую просьбу (это слово этикета, которое всегда обособляется).

Это же слово может иметь **другие значения**, и тогда оно считается **частицей.**

Частица **обособляется или не обособляется по ситуации, в соответствии со структурой и интонацией предложения,** что видно из приведенных по ссылке примеров.

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ! Что делает "пожалуйста" вводным словом? Оно выражает отношение к сказанному? Служит для оформления? Нет и нет. Оно выражает эмоции говорящего, что характерно для обычных частиц. "Частица вежливости", если хотите. Зачем ее обособлять?

Comment: Вводные слова эмоции выражают очень активно — радость, сожаление, удивление и т. п. (к счастью, к несчастью, по счастью, по несчастью, к радости, к огорчению...).  Эта вводная функция  "частицы вежливости"  (ее можно убрать из предложения) принципиально отличаются от тех случаев, когда  пожалуйста замещает какое-то слово (можно, согласен и др.). "Согласие или разрешение" убрать нельзя.  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122

Comment: И вывод. Вводное слово "пожалуйста" не входит в основное содержание предложения (это попутная вежливость, без которой можно обойтись, поэтому оно обособляется). Частица "пожалуйста" относится к основному содержанию предложения, выражая указание, согласие, разрешение. Она может обособляться, оставаясь членом предложения, если этого требует его структура.

Comment: Тогда что является критерием "вводности"? Можно убрать/передвинуть? Так обычные частицы тоже можно... ведь... же. Спасибо еще раз за ваши ответы!

Comment: Пожалуйста. Про критерий вводности: водные слова не входят в содержание и струтуру предложения, это пометки автора, его отношение к сообщению или оформление сообщения. Это причина. А то, что можно убрать вводное слово, - это формальное следствие.  Эти категории иногда трудно различить, но желательно. Спасибо еще раз Вам за Ваш вопрос.

Comment: А вот тут мы подходим к самому интересному. Как вы решаете, входит ли данная частица в содержание и структуру предложения? Например, "Скажите, пожалуйста!" vs "Ну, скажите же!"